# Pandas subset dataframe based on column value that alphabetically

Tags: python, pandas

I have huge dataset where i need to subset the data based on the letter it begins with.

df:

| name | price |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 20 |
| Orange | 35 |
| Watermelon | 10 |
| Banana | 5 |

I need to subset data that beginswith a to i in as one set, j to r as another, s to z as another set. Is there any other way than below

```
alpha1 = [‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’, ‘d’, ‘e’, ‘f’, ‘g’, ‘h’, ‘i’]
alpha2 = [‘j’, ‘k’, ‘l’, ‘m’, ‘n’, ‘o’, ‘p’, ‘q’, ‘r’]
alpha3 = [‘s’, ‘t’, ‘u’, ‘v’, ‘w’, ‘x’, ‘y’, ‘z’]

df1 = df[df['name'].str.startswith(alpha1)]
df2 = df[df['name'].str.startswith(alpha2)]
df3 = df[df['name'].str.startswith(alpha3)]
```

Comment: `df['name'].str.match('[a-i]')` and so on

Comment: I actually need to subset based on the alphabet it starts with

Comment: yes, I know, and?

Comment: So if a column value begins with a to i, I have to subset it and if it begins with j to r it should be considered as another subset and so on

Comment: yes, that's what `df['name'].str.match('[a-i]')` does. You can add `flags=re.IGNORECASE` to make the check case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = df.loc[df['name'][0] in 'abcdefghi']
df2 = df.loc[df['name'][0] in 'jklmnopqr']
df3 = df.loc[df['name'][0] in 'stuvwxyz']
```

Try this, hope this works